# Creating relation between tables in Movie Database

Tags: sql

I have created a movie database that contain following tables :

1.Film
2.People
3.Genres
4.Role
5.Users

Here is my sql

```
create table Film ( id INT(30),title varchar(30),images varchar(30)
primary key (id));
create table people(id INT(30),Fname varchar(30),Lname varchar(30),
primary key (id));
create table Role(id INT(30), name varchar(30),
primary key(id));
```

i want create relation between Film,People and Role table.SO my Question is do i need to create a table to make relation between those table and is it necessary to use auto_increment for id column?

Comment: What you've tried ? And have you looked for JOIN and Foreign Key ?

Comment: @KaushikKishore i have tried to add foreign key but i can not figure out that i should have at least one similar column to add foreign key between films and people but what column would that be ? i have tried to create a table called Film_people and tried join three tables but showing and sql error 150

Comment: that  sounds like a different question then... please upvote our excellent responses and post another question.

Comment: Do like this. Create a column RelatedFilmId in your table `Role` that will be FilmId from `Film`. and then JOIN The Table you'll get the result.

Comment: This must be some course assignment; I swear I saw this question already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to create some tables like:

```
FilmRole( FilmId INT, RoleId INT) these 2 columns would make your PK and they are also FK's to their 
FilmPeople (FilmId INT, PeopleId INT)  respective source tables.
FilmUsers( FilmId INT, UserId INT)
```

You could add a single `IDENTITY` (for SQL Server for example) column to each table if you wanted but in this particular case a 2 column PK is adequate as these tables simply point to other records.

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot but one thing you did not address from question above is that the auto_increment.If i use auto_increment with id would there be any problem? i mean if one record is deleted from the table.

Comment: having an auto increment would work just fine, it's not how I would do it in this scenario but would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your table and add in a foreign key (Primary key in one table and attribute in another). Examples how to do it here! http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Yeah but you can suggest this in comment or you can briefly explain your answer and add a reference in bottom

Comment: I gave a reference and a brief explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
do i need to create a table to make relation between those table ?
```

YES ! to enforce Referential integrity [read this](http://www.lightwolftech.com/index.php?page=backgrounders)

```
is it necessary to use auto_increment for id column?
```

Depends but it is most prefered way of creating a PK on a table